# react-admin change data before passed to edit component

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

In react-admin the `Edit` component loads the record and prefills the form with the record values.
I am using `TranslatableInputs` and my problem is that the record data structure differs from the one required/returned by `TranslatableInputs`.
So when I view the edit form it just renders the inputs empty.
Is there a way to transform my data before it is passed to `TranslatableInputs`?

Format returned by translatable inputs:

```js
{
  [field: string]: Record<string, string>
}
```

But my model has the following format:

```js
{
  translations: Record<string, Record<string, string>>;
}
```

Edit form:

```js
<Edit>
    <SimpleForm>
        <TextInput source="color" type="color" sx={{minWidth: 100}} />
        <Box sx={{width: "50%", maxWidth: "100%"}} >
            <TranslatableInputs locales={["en", "es", "de"]}>
                <TextInput source="name" fullWidth />
                <TextInput source="synonyms" multiline fullWidth/>
            </TranslatableInputs>
        </Box>
    </SimpleForm>
</Edit>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your translation data format - and example would help.

`TranslatableInput` doesn't support `parse` and `format`, so you have to fall back to [the `<Edit transform>` property](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Edit.html#transform):

```
<Edit transform={convertData}>
    <SimpleForm>
        <TextInput source="color" type="color" sx={{minWidth: 100}} />
        <Box sx={{width: "50%", maxWidth: "100%"}} >
            <TranslatableInputs locales={["en", "es", "de"]}>
                <TextInput source="name" fullWidth />
                <TextInput source="synonyms" multiline fullWidth/>
            </TranslatableInputs>
        </Box>
    </SimpleForm>
</Edit>
```

With the following transformation code:

```
const convertData = record => ({
   ...record,
   translations: [convert data here]
})
```

Comment: It doesnt matter what my forma is,whats important is that its different than the one fron TranslatableInput. `transform` only transforms data after submit before it is sent but I want to change data after the record is loaded and before the data is passed to the form fields. For now I have just created my own input component to support my format.

Comment: You're right, `transform` is for transforming data after it's submitted. If you need to transform data before passing it to the form, you probably need to do it in the data provider, or, as you did, in a custom component.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue and I have several fields to parse.
The workaround with `RecordContext.Consumer` worked for me. Probably, the same behavior can be achieved with `useContext(RecordContext)`.

```
import {
  Edit,
  SimpleForm,
  RecordContext
} from "react-admin";

<Edit>
  <RecordContext.Consumer>
    {value => {
      const parsedValue = parseData(value);
      return (
        <SimpleForm record={parsedValue}>
          <MyForm />
        </SimpleForm>
       )}
     }
  </RecordContext.Consumer>
</Edit>
```